# Cannot have a steady connection with my Bluetooth smartwatch in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Pls, I'm having problems having a steady connection between my android app and my smartwatch, anytime the app connect with the watch, it connect and disconnect immediately. I actually use a custom crrp sdk for the project

This is the scan activity

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.crrepa.ble.CRPBleClient;
import com.crrepa.ble.conn.CRPBleDevice;
import com.crrepa.ble.conn.listener.CRPBleFirmwareUpgradeListener;
import com.crrepa.ble.scan.bean.CRPScanDevice;
import com.crrepa.ble.scan.callback.CRPScanCallback;
import com.crrepa.ble.trans.upgrade.bean.HSFirmwareInfo;
import com.crrepa.sdk.sample.PermissionUtils;
import com.crrepa.sdk.sample.R;
import com.crrepa.sdk.sample.SampleApplication;
import com.crrepa.sdk.sample.device.DeviceActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "ScanActivity";
    private static final int SCAN_PERIOD = 10 * 1000;

    private static final int REQUEST_UPDATEBANDCONFIG = 4;
    private static final String[] PERMISSION_UPDATEBANDCONFIG = new String[] {
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"};

    @BindView(R.id.btn_scan_toggle)
    Button scanToggleBtn;
    @BindView(R.id.scan_results)
    RecyclerView scanResults;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_firmware_fix_state)
    TextView tvFirmwareFixState;


    private CRPBleClient mBleClient;
    private ScanResultsAdapter mResultsAdapter;
    private boolean mScanState = false;


    private static final String UPGRADE_APP_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + File.separator + "crrepa" + File.separator + "app_band-hs.bin";
    private static final String UPGRADE_USER_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + File.separator + "crrepa" + File.separator + "usr.bin";
    private static final String USER_START_ADDRESS = "23000";
//    private static final String BAND_ADDRESS = "C1:C4:7C:DE:44:5B";
//    private static final String BAND_ADDRESS = "D9:4D:C2:BB:F3:F4";
    private static final String BAND_ADDRESS = "FB:09:C5:C7:1A:90";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mBleClient = SampleApplication.getBleClient(this);

        configureResultList();

        requestPermissions();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cancelScan();
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.btn_scan_toggle, R.id.btn_firmware_fix, R.id.btn_hs_upgrade})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
        if (!mBleClient.isBluetoothEnable()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            return;
        }

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_scan_toggle:
                if (mScanState) {
                    cancelScan();
                } else {
                    startScan();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btn_firmware_fix:

                break;
            case R.id.btn_hs_upgrade:
                CRPBleClient bleClient = SampleApplication.getBleClient(this);
                CRPBleDevice bleDevice = bleClient.getBleDevice(BAND_ADDRESS);
                HSFirmwareInfo upgradeInfo = new HSFirmwareInfo();
                upgradeInfo.setAppFilePath(UPGRADE_APP_FILE_PATH);
                upgradeInfo.setUserFilePath(UPGRADE_USER_FILE_PATH);
                upgradeInfo.setUserStartAddress(USER_START_ADDRESS);


                break;
        }

    }

    private void startScan() {
        boolean success = mBleClient.scanDevice(new CRPScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanning(final CRPScanDevice device) {
                Log.d(TAG, "address: " + device.getDevice().getAddress());
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(device.getDevice().getName())) {
                    return;
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mResultsAdapter.addScanResult(device);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanComplete(List<CRPScanDevice> results) {
                if (mScanState) {
                    mScanState = false;
                    updateButtonUIState();
                }
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        if (success) {
            mScanState = true;
            updateButtonUIState();
            mResultsAdapter.clearScanResults();
        }
    }

    private void cancelScan() {
        mBleClient.cancelScan();
    }


    private void configureResultList() {
        scanResults.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager recyclerLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        scanResults.setLayoutManager(recyclerLayoutManager);
        mResultsAdapter = new ScanResultsAdapter();
        scanResults.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);
        mResultsAdapter.setOnAdapterItemClickListener(new ScanResultsAdapter.OnAdapterItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdapterViewClick(View view) {
                final int childAdapterPosition = scanResults.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                final CRPScanDevice itemAtPosition = mResultsAdapter.getItemAtPosition(childAdapterPosition);
                onAdapterItemClick(itemAtPosition);
            }
        });
    }


    private void onAdapterItemClick(CRPScanDevice scanResults) {
        final String macAddress = scanResults.getDevice().getAddress();
        mBleClient.cancelScan();

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DeviceActivity.DEVICE_MACADDR, macAddress);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    private void updateButtonUIState() {
        scanToggleBtn.setText(mScanState ? R.string.stop_scan : R.string.start_scan);
    }

    CRPBleFirmwareUpgradeListener mFirmwareUpgradeListener = new CRPBleFirmwareUpgradeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFirmwareDownloadStarting() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFirmwareDownloadStarting");
            updateTextView(tvFirmwareFixState, getString(R.string.dfu_status_download_starting));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFirmwareDownloadComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFirmwareDownloadComplete");
            updateTextView(tvFirmwareFixState, getString(R.string.dfu_status_download_complete));
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgradeProgressStarting() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgradeProgressStarting");
            updateTextView(tvFirmwareFixState, getString(R.string.dfu_status_starting));
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgradeProgressChanged(int percent, float speed) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgradeProgressChanged: " + percent);
            String status = String.format(getString(R.string.dfu_status_uploading_part), percent);
            updateTextView(tvFirmwareFixState, status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgradeCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgradeCompleted");
            updateTextView(tvFirmwareFixState, getString(R.string.dfu_status_completed));
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgradeAborted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgradeAborted");
            updateTextView(tvFirmwareFixState, getString(R.string.dfu_status_aborted));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int errorType, String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + errorType);
            updateTextView(tvFirmwareFixState, message);
        }
    };

    void updateTextView(final TextView view, final String con) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setText(con);
            }
        });
    }


    void requestPermissions() {
        if (!PermissionUtils.hasSelfPermissions(this, PERMISSION_UPDATEBANDCONFIG)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, PERMISSION_UPDATEBANDCONFIG, REQUEST_UPDATEBANDCONFIG);
        }
    }
}
```

and the device activity here where  data is transferred between the watch and the app

````
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceActivity";
    public static final String DEVICE_MACADDR = "device_macaddr";

    private static final String UI_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + "crrepa" + File.separator + "ota" + File.separator
            + "eaf49ccb4dbe5df51af35803662867d5.bin";

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    CRPBleClient mBleClient;
    CRPBleDevice mBleDevice;
    CRPBleConnection mBleConnection;
    boolean isUpgrade = false;

    @BindView(R.id.tv_connect_state)
    TextView tvConnectState;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_firmware_version)
    TextView tvFirmwareVersion;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_battery)
    TextView tvBattery;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_step)
    TextView tvStep;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_distance)
    TextView tvDistance;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_calorie)
    TextView tvCalorie;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_restful)
    TextView tvRestful;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_light)
    TextView tvLight;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_heart_rate)
    TextView tvHeartRate;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_blood_pressure)
    TextView tvBloodPressure;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_upgrade_state)
    TextView tvUpgradeState;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_ble_connect_state)
    Button btnBleDisconnect;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_blood_oxygen)
    TextView tvBloodOxygen;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_new_firmware_version)
    TextView tvNewFirmwareVersion;

    private String bandFirmwareVersion;

    private List<Integer> supportWatchFaceList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        initView();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        String macAddr = getIntent().getStringExtra(DEVICE_MACADDR);
        //BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(macAddr)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mBleClient = SampleApplication.getBleClient(this);
        mBleDevice = mBleClient.getBleDevice(macAddr);
        if (mBleDevice != null && !mBleDevice.isConnected()) {
            connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBleDevice != null) {
            mBleDevice.disconnect();
        }
    }

    void initView() {
        updateStepInfo(0, 0, 0);
        updateSleepInfo(0, 0);
    }



    void connect() {
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mBleDevice.connect();
                mBleConnection = mBleDevice.connect();

        mBleConnection.setConnectionStateListener(new CRPBleConnectionStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(int newState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange: " + newState);
                int state = -1;
                switch (newState) {
                    case CRPBleConnectionStateListener.STATE_CONNECTED:
        DeviceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//                state = R.string.state_connected;
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                updateTextView(btnBleDisconnect, getString(R.string.disconnect));
                Toast.makeText(DeviceActivity.this, "connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

                        testSet();
                        break;
                    case CRPBleConnectionStateListener.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        state = R.string.state_connecting;
                        break;
                    case CRPBleConnectionStateListener.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                        //closeGatt();
                        state = R.string.state_disconnected;
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        updateTextView(btnBleDisconnect, getString(R.string.connect));
                        break;
                }
                updateConnectState(state);
            }
        });

        mBleConnection.setStepChangeListener(mStepChangeListener);
        mBleConnection.setSleepChangeListener(mSleepChangeListener);
        mBleConnection.setHeartRateChangeListener(mHeartRateChangListener);
        mBleConnection.setBloodPressureChangeListener(mBloodPressureChangeListener);
        mBleConnection.setBloodOxygenChangeListener(mBloodOxygenChangeListener);
        mBleConnection.setFindPhoneListener(mFindPhoneListener);
        mBleConnection.setECGChangeListener(mECGChangeListener, CRPEcgMeasureType.TI);
        mBleConnection.setStepsCategoryListener(mStepsCategoryChangeListener);
        mBleConnection.setSleepActionChangeListener(mSleepActionChangeListener);
        mBleConnection.setMovementStateListener(mMovementStateListener);
        mBleConnection.setTempChangeListener(mTempChangeListener);
        mBleConnection.setContactListener(mContactListener);
        mBleConnection.setHrvChangeListener(mHrvChangeListener);
    }

    private void closeGatt() {
        if (mBleConnection != null) {
            mBleConnection.close();
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Do you have a log output? What is the reason for the disconnect?

Comment: It was not giving any log error

Comment: Hard to help you then. There are often questions about BLE devices disconnecting on their own here. This often happens if you do not have the right access rights to the device or the device is using some kind of custom security and you are missing some info you need to send as well.